# How can I create a JUnit test to test CompareTo?

Tags: java, arrays, junit, int, compare

In my code I have two static methods. One that I am using to compare the contents of two arrays of int's, and one that is comparing the contents of two arrays of strings (in the same order). How can I structure a JUnit test for one of these methods? I'm thinking that I could use
EDIT**
I created a test that works however is not accurate.

```
//edited test, passes but clearly isn't correct.
    public class ArrayComparerTests {
        @Test
        public void testIntArray() {
    //      ArrayComparer arrayComparer = new ArrayComparer();
            int[] list1 = {2,2,3};
            int[] list2 = {1};
            assertEquals(false, ArrayComparer.compareIntArrays(list1, list2));
        }

    }


  public class ArrayComparer {
        public static boolean compareIntArrays(int[] list1, int[] list2) {

            // checks for same array reference
            if (list1 == list2) {
                return true;
            }

            // checks for null arrays
            if (list1 == null || list2 == null) {
                return false;
            }

            // arrays should be of equal length
            if (list2.length != list1.length) {
                return false;
            }

            // compare array values
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
                    if (list1[i] != list2[i])
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


        public static boolean compareStringArrays(String[] list3, String[] list4) {
            // checks for same array reference
            if (list3 == list4) {
                return true;
            }

            // checks for null arrays
            if (list3 == null || list4 == null) {
                return false;
            }

            // arrays should be of equal length
            if (list4.length != list3.length) {
                return false;
            }

            // compare array values
            for (int i = 0; i < list3.length; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < list4.length; i++) {
                    if (list3[i] != list4[i])
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you just create a function that compares each element of the array with each other, assuming they are the same size and just break if something isnt the same have the function return false and just do an assert true (or false depending on what outcome you are expecting) as your unit test?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [Assert.assertArrayEquals](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals%28int[],%20int[]%29).

```
@Test
public void testIntArray() {
    int[] list1 = {2,2,3};
    int[] list2 = {1};
    // assertion fail
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(list2, list1);

    // assertion pass
    int list3 = {2,2,3};
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(list1, list3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This is the answer.

```
public class ArrayComparerTests {
    @Test
    public void testIntArray() {
        int[] list1 = {2,2,3};
        int[] list2 = {1};
        assertEquals(false, ArrayComparer.compareIntArrays(list1, list2));
    }

}
```